# Better $_GET security

Tags: php

My PHP is very rusty. I have a md5 hash that's being passed via get to a script and then I'm grabbing it like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Obviously there's a security risk here...I was thinking of checking the string length to make sure it's 32 characters long but that doesn't seem very robust to me. What else could I do to make it more secure?

thanks

Comment: Why are you passing a hash via get? Without more info, I'd guess that the way you're doing this is fundamentally insecure.

Comment: What are you doing with `$id` after you get it?

Comment: Whether there's a security risk will mostly depend on what you do with the variable afterwards.

Comment: It's a link in an email..the user clicks it and gets directed to a page where that hash is used to validate them...a call is made to the db to see if there's a record with that hash id in it..if there is then they're allowed to update their details...as I said my php is rusty but many sites seem to use this method?

Comment: MD5 hash can have 16^32 possible values, so it's good enough for unique links as long as input data for generating hash is non-guessable. E.g., for password change requests (when user has forgotten his password) it's enough to use `md5($userID . $userEmail . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'])`, as it's quite impossible to guess when exactly (request_time) and which user (user id, email) asked to change the password. Hash itself is also hard-to-guess as it can have huge number of possible values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could validate with a regex to make sure it consists of only alphanumeric characters.

E.g. something like this (my PHP is rusty too):

```
if(preg_match("/^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$/", $id) > 0) {
    // All good
}
```

Comment: I just noticed my regex was wrong (included A-Z) - have edited now.

Comment: Wouldn't that match any string that contains 32 hexadecimal digits in sequence, rather than only strings consisting of exactly 32 hexadecimal digits (which I imagine you want to do)? Assuming the input is such, anchor the regex at both ends. `^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$`.

Comment: actually that gices me an error: Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Unknown modifier '{' in C:\wamp\www\winners.php on line 9 ...my code is like this : if(preg_match("[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}", $_GET['id']) > 0) {
   $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
}  any ideas?

Comment: @elduderino The regex is valid - are you definitely looking at the right line? Try surrounding the pattern with / so it looks like this: /^[A-Fa-f0-9]{32}$/

Comment: Yeah sorted now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

First of I assume you are using >= PHP5.2. I actually would advice you to use PHP5.3 because it is faster without even modifying codebase. I use the [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) extension to secure my codebase.

```
/* prevent XSS. */
$_GET   = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_POST  = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: This is the solution, Thanks bud

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `preg_match` to ckeck the presence of only **alnum** and 32 length.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do with the id. If you create a mysql select with this, you should add `mysql_real_escape_string` ([php.net/mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)). For output purpose, you could just convert the string to html entities with htmlentities ([php.net/htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)) or use the filter extension ([php.net/filter](http://php.net/filter))

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [Security with PHP Superglobals](http://www.faqs.org/docs/gazette/superglobals.html)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make some sort of "filters" and apply them to the $_GET['id'] var , among these filters you could check length, type, allowed character types, required or not ...
2. Pass a random generated string ( hashed ) as a hidden element in you're form each time you're form is rendered, save the string on generation in you're session and on form sumbit check for that first, if they don't match then you don't eaven need to bother checking the id or other elements sent .
3. Use post instead of get where possible .

Answer (score 0):

Example using [ctype-alnum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php):

```
if (strlen($id) == 32 && ctype_alnum($id)) exit('pass');
else exit('no');
```